# Dynamic RNN: padding word vector

Tags: tensorflow, padding, recurrent-neural-network

I am a bit confused on padding, my first question is:

- Is it possible to pad a shorter sequence with values that are not 0? How do you deal with that then in the RNN?
- Generally a 0 is used for padding, is there a specific reason why? Does it make it easy in the training because it does not affect the calculation or you still need to mask the loss function?
- In case your sentence is composed of vectors embedding from a word2vec model, would padding be applied as a zero vector?

Thanks in advance fir any hint!

Comment: [`tf.pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) offers options to use a different constant value, as well as alternative padding methods. Zero is frequently used by convention, so it is easier to ignore pad values later (for RNN processing and for optimization); although you also have [`tf.sequence_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is addressed in [How to overcome training example's different lengths when working with Word Embeddings (word2vec)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13120/how-to-overcome-training-examples-different-lengths-when-working-with-word-embe).

For details on the alternating min/max padding method, see [Apply word embeddings to entire document, to get a feature vector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221715/apply-word-embeddings-to-entire-document-to-get-a-feature-vector).

See also: [keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences), which can take a value to pad with as an argument.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*